# Why is the value not displaying in my redux form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I can't get data populated in Fields when the page is initially displayed...

I was under the assumption that if I defined finYear, then it would automatically use the name of the attributes within finYear and map it to the `<Field name="totalFixedAssets">` attribute?

```
import React from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { fetchFinancialYear } from "../actions/financialYearActions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class FirstForm extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchFinancialYear(this.props.match.params.id));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div>
          <div>{this.props.finYear.totalFixedAssets}</div>
          <label>Total Fixed Assets</label>
          <Field name="totalFixedAssets" component="input" />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  finYear: state.financialYearReducer.financialYear
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  // ...
});

FirstForm = reduxForm({
  form: "firstForm"
})(FirstForm);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps // bind account loading action creator
)(FirstForm);
```

reducer code...

```
import {
  FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_BEGIN,
  FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_FAILURE
} from "../actions/financialYearActions";

const initialState = {
  financialYear: {},
  loading: false,
  error: null
};

function financialYearReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null
      };

    case FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        financialYear: action.payload.financialYear
      };

    case FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload.error,
        financialYear: {}
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default financialYearReducer;
```

action code...

```
import axios from "axios";

export const FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_BEGIN = "FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_BEGIN";
export const FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_SUCCESS = "FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_SUCCESS";
export const FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_FAILURE = "FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_FAILURE";

export const fetchFinancialYearBegin = () => ({
  type: FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_BEGIN
});

export const fetchFinancialYearSuccess = financialYear => ({
  type: FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_SUCCESS,
  payload: { financialYear }
});

export const fetchFinancialYearFailure = error => ({
  type: FETCH_FINANCIAL_YEAR_FAILURE,
  payload: { error }
});

export function fetchFinancialYear(financialYearUuid) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchFinancialYearBegin());
    const accountRequest = {
      financialYearUuid: financialYearUuid,
      userUuid: "asdf"
    };
    return axios
      .post("/account/service/fetch/single", accountRequest)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(fetchFinancialYearSuccess(res.data.financialYear));
        return res.data;
      })
      .catch(error => dispatch(fetchFinancialYearFailure(error)));
  };
}

function handleErrors(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw Error(response.statusText);
  }
  return response;
}
```

I have successfully returned data from the API call and I can display it in the `<div>{this.props.finYear.totalFixedAssets}</div>` on the form, although I am trying to display the value in the `<Field name="totalFixedAssets" component="input" />` in the form, but it is always blank.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is on 
`<Field name="totalFixedAssets" component="input" />`

Try just changing it to 
`<Field name="financialYear.totalFixedAssets" component="input" />`

You need to provide the entire path to the value. Field's name is a string path in dot-and-bracket notation.

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/04zrxoyk10

There is an issue in redux-forms where if you have the data already added in the store it is no rendered. https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/621

Comment: unfortunately that also doesn't display a value in the Field

Comment: I write the wrong name, change finYear --> financialYear (updated answer)

Comment: No, sorry - changing it to financialYear.totalFixedAssets made no difference

Comment: If you force a reload you should see the data